# What is the reason behind Visual Studio 2019 defaulting to the C++ 14 standard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to use inline variables, but found out VS defaults to C++14 and one must manually change this on a project by project basis. Why doesn't Microsoft automatically update VS to the C++17 standard for all projects?

Comment: The default standard version is usually updated when a vendor feels they support it sufficiently well.

Comment: You can tell VS to use the C++17 standard right now if you wanted to. They even have a chunk of C++20 supported if you wanted to try it out.

Comment: The standard was published nearly 3 years ago. It seems like this discourages a wider adoption. Isn't C++17 thoroughly vetted to the point where it should be automatically implemented on all new versions of VS?

Comment: It's just a default. If one needs/wants the features, they can easily turn them on. It's worth noting that gcc and clang also default to C++14 currently. I also doubt it would foster wider adoption. You'll code to C++17 or you won't. The compiler default has zero bearing on that.

Comment: Right, but you can code like you're using C++14 with C++17, so why not default to C++17? There are 0 downsides to forcing the C++17 default on everyone whereas the C++14 default adds an unnecessary encumbrance on using expected functionality.

Comment: My understanding (which I vaguely recall from when I worked at Microsoft on Visual Studio) is that Visual Studio will default to the latest C++ that is sufficiently supported.  There may be some [C++17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) features that are missing, so it doesn't make the bar yet.

Comment: I see zero downsides for the reverse as well. `-std=c++NN` belongs in every project's compile command regardless of the compiler default.

Comment: @Eljay ok thank you, perhaps I am being impatient. Little things like this drive me crazy.

Comment: @happysaint `The standard was published nearly 3 years ago` you mean during the pandemic? And how well does *any* compiler support all of it? Especially the "juicy" parts like ... UTF8 conversion? For a time (perhaps still) there was no standard way to do that. gcc users complain the compiler changes under their feet all the time. Never mind regressions caused by fast changes. That's OK if you want to test the latest features, not good at all if you want to push your next production release without surprises

Comment: @happysaint `There are 0 downsides to forcing the C++17 default` on the contrary, [codecvt_utf8 was deprecated in C++ 17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8). That's a big deal. Unless all your customers are in the US, that's a show-stopper.